# Installing latest version of Dancer2 on Debian

Tags: perl, debian, dancer

OK, got myself a clean virtual machine running Debian 9 (Stretch). I installed [Dancer2](https://packages.debian.org/source/stable/libdancer2-perl) from the Debian package system. It's running version 0.204002. The Dancer2 software is telling me that the latest version is 0.205002.

I want to finally, once and for all, learn the proper way to upgrade Perl modules on a Debian machine to the latest and greatest versions without ruining the Debian `dpkg` dependencies. How do I achieve this?

**EDIT**
Yes, this is a development machine I'm just playing with. But what if I wanted to run the latest version of Dancer 2 on a production machine? How would I do it?

Comment: `cpan Dancer2`? The downside of CPAN is that you cannot uninstall (easily) and it won't auto-update.

Comment: @PerlDuck `cpanm` [allows you to uninstall](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-cpanminus/bin/cpanm#-uninstall,-U), if there is a proper packlist.

Comment: I've closed your question as a duplicate. The first and second answer of that question are spot-on. The second is more modern. Please consider _not using the system Perl_ in production. On your fresh VM this is fine, if it's only for development. But as soon as that box does anything else, you might mess up something, because the system Perl is meant for the system. Some core Linux utilities use it, and stuff like Dancer has a huge dependency chain, so a lot of things might get updated when you install it, and that could break things, especially if your dist had custom patches on modules.

Comment: Right, this is a development machine. But I want to learn how to do it properly as if it were a production machine.

Comment: If i wanted to run the latest version of Dancer 2 on a production machine, how would I do it properly?

Comment: @simbabque I don't like the 2nd answer in the post you refer to because it uses `sudo` to run CPAN. I think your list of answers is ordered differently.

Comment: @PerlDuck I meant the one with 50ish votes. It does use `sudo` to install, yes. But it also talks about cpanm's bootstrapping technique, which is fine. There should be something about local::lib. I think there is another such question that we often use a dup target, but I can't find it right now. If you find a better target, I'll reopen and change it.

Comment: The answers to that question you marked mine as a duplicate of don't answer my question at all.

Comment: I have reopened. The fact that you are running Debian doesn't really matter. There is some stuff in the Dancer documentation. I will write something down here later.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell that the following is the answer for the *I want to finally, once and for all, learn the proper way...* , but this is how me doing it in all my deployments.

1. Install **anyenv** `sudo git clone https://github.com/riywo/anyenv /opt/anyenv` - you could deploy it into your `$HOME` as `git clone https://github.com/riywo/anyenv ~/.anyenv` but myself prefering some commonly accessible place. This step isn't mandatory, but for me help managing other local installations as `node` and such.
2. change ownership: `sudo chown -R jm666 /opt/anyenv` - you will manage the content
3. add into the `.profile`:

```
export ANYENV_ROOT=/opt/anyenv
export PATH="$ANYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(anyenv init -)"
```

Relog, or run `exec $SHELL -l`. Now you have installed an helper for all commonly needed environments.

Now install the `perl` env. helper, called `plenv`.

```
anyenv install plenv
```

Or follow the [guide in the repo](https://github.com/tokuhirom/plenv) if you don't want the previous `anyenv` step.

And finally install fresh `perl` using `plenv`:

```
plenv install -l #will display all available perl versions
plenv install 5.26.1 -j 8 # number of proc cores or less. :)
```

This will take some time - on my notebook 4m23,186s - just tested :).

```
plenv global 5.26.1 # now all `perl script.pl` will use the freshly installed perl
plenv install-cpanm
plenv rehash #needed if you install some commands which should be accesible from `bash`
```

And you're ready to install any perl modules using `cpanm` - without compromising the system-wide installed perl. Everything will be installed into the `plenv`'s directory tree. Even, you never need be `root`.

This way I could manage to have the same development and deployment environment. Maybe here is a better way - but for me the above works.

In short, read:

- https://github.com/riywo/anyenv
- https://github.com/tokuhirom/plenv